# how to unlink a file in a foreach loop with post

Tags: php, unlink, file-management

For a file management I use a `foreach` loop in which all the files are displayed. Now I want `foreach` to delete files with `$_POST`.

When I echo `pathinfo($dir.'/'.$file, PATHINFO_DIRNAME).'/'.$file;` in the foreach near each file, it shows me the exact location of the files.
Now for each file I want do something like this in the `foreach` loop:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    unlink($_POST['unlink']);
}
<form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="unlink" value="<?php pathinfo($dir.'/'.$file, PATHINFO_DIRNAME).'/'.$file; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="delete"  value="Delete">
         </form>
```

I know this is not correct but i hope you understand that what i want to achieve is clear. 
How can I do this?

Comment: And you don't think that will end bad?

Comment: what about adding `echo` that will actually print the path? Totally unsecure BTW

Comment: Do you wish to delete files one-by-one or multiple at a time?

Comment: What happens with this code?

Comment: it looks like it could work with an `echo`, but you'll have to use a loop as you've already identified. one suggestion might be to change the input names as arrays, so try `name="unlink[]"`. make sure you've got permissions set appropriately on files so that only what you want deleted has a chance

Comment: @chris85 Now nothing happens; the file is not deleted

Comment: Seriously rethink what you are doing. You will need at the very least: authentication, csrf protection and directory traversal protection.

Comment: Sending user-submitted data directly to `unlink`grants any user the ability to delete any file on your server which unlink has access to. Make sure you're validating the data before unlinking anything.

Answer (score 1):

## DISCLAIMER

The method outlined below is 100% insecure and if the code makes it into the public realm then you can kiss your server goodbye.

---

For deleting one file you can do this:

**index.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="delete.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete_path" value="/path/to/your/file.pdf">
    File.pdf <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
$delete_result = false;
$unlink_error = '';

if(isset($_POST['delete_path']) && is_file($_POST['delete_path']))
{
    $delete_result = unlink($_POST['delete_path']);
    $unlink_error = error_get_last();
}

if($delete_result)
{
    echo 'Successfully deleted '.$_POST['delete_path'];
}
else
{
    echo 'Uh oh, Spaghettios :(<br><br>';
    echo 'Last known error<br>'.$unlink_error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am use path unlink(**FILE**)
                           echo $new_file_dert = **FILE** . '/'.$template_name;

```
                            <form method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="unlink" value="<?php echo $new_file_dert; ?>" />
                                <input name="delete" type="submit" class="btn-delete submitdelete" value="Delete">
                            </form>    



                         <?php
```

echo $new_file_dert = **FILE** .  '/'.$template_name;

```
                             if( isset( $_POST['delete'] ) ) {
                                 unlink($_POST['unlink']);



                             }
```